# Launch Application in Mac and Windows

Tags: windows, macos

I have my application installed on the user's machine(both windows and mac users). Now the user also  goes to my web site for certain other things. I want to provide a link in the web site which says "Launch my app". When he clicks on the link, it should launch my application, which has been installed on his system. I was thinking of going the Active X route but it is not recommended + have to use another approach for Mac. The other option was some how get a file association with my application and make it work. Is there any other option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could register your application for special URL schemas, like `mygreatapp://open`. In the same way that an `ftp://...` link opens the default FTP app and a `mailto://...` link opens the default email application, you can register your own app for any custom `[myuniqueschemahere]://` schema.

Answer (score 1):

Register your app as a "helper" app for browsers as part of the installer process.

So if you have a link on your website with a URL like "prashant://thisfineapp", clicking on it launches your application.